# React browser push showing page before redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi there just small question , I got react redirect with

```
browserHistory.push('/login/');
```

Everything works fine but before i will be redirected to login page i can see for a 1.2 sec Page that is only for logged users ( without of data from json but still empty rows ) how can I avoid that ?

Comment: How do you check when should you redirect? I guess you are waiting for a 401 error and when it arrives you redirect to login, am I right?

Comment: Which version of React Router are you using?